# global object not working in Visual Studio Code [ JavaScript ]

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

I have the following code:

```
var myFriend = 'David';
function Hi(){
   var myFriend = 'Emma';
   console.log(global.myFriend); //prints undefined
}
Hi();
```

I am trying to access the global variable myFriend inside the function. I am unable to understand why it is printing undefined. Can someone please explain?

Comment: When you say `returns undefined`, do you mean that it **prints** the word "undefined"? The word "return" has a technical meaning in programming that isn't related to what you are doing here.

Comment: What environment are you running this in?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, yes it prints undefined.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder environment is Node.js

Comment: Cool, thanks for confirming. Then the problem is that your code is being run at module scope, not global scope, and so `var myFriend` is not creating a global. Node.js runs your code in a module scope by default. See the linked question's answers for more details. Happy coding!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I understand now. Thanks!

Comment: If you remove the first `var` keyword you would be assigning to an implicit global and it would log `David` as expected. Also if you log `global.myFriend` immediately after the first statement, you would get the same behaviour as you do in the closure.

Comment: @Paulpro You are right. I just tried out your solution and it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: I kind of disagree that this is a duplicate question -- although there are helpful details in the linked answer, asking 'why is this a thing" and 'what is the default' are two different things -- the latter implies more knowledge of what's going on, and the asker of the former wouldn't search for those words.